# Update Manager asking me to update kernel but apt-get upgrade does not?

Tags: kernel, update-manager

Just what the title says. The update manager is also asking me to update to Ubuntu 12.10 even when I have the part unchecked that says "Check for new Ubuntu version updates" thing. Is there some way to turn the annoying update manager off?

Comment: have you run sudo apt-get update ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `apt-get upgrade` does not install new packages.

Due to the way the kernel packages are built, every new (bugfix) version of the package actually has a different name. Plus you install a metapackage, which will always depend on the latest kernel.

This has as a sideeffect, that updating the metapackage for the kernel always requires a new package to be installed (the new kernel), which update-manager will happily do for you.

`apt-get upgrade` however will strictly upgrade packages, and will not install new packages. If you run `apt-get upgrade`, you will see that the kernel metapackage is being held back (for this reason, though it doesn't give you the reason).

So instead of `apt-get upgrade`, run `apt-get dist-upgrade` to update the kernel metapackage and install the latest kernel version.

Comment: But I do not want to update to 12.10 (I have 12.04 LTS because it works with AMD graphics better). So will updating the kernel update me to 12.10?

Comment: Why I'm asking is because one of the packages has the word quazal in it.

Comment: dist-upgrade does not upgrade to a new release, it just means 'allow installing/removing additional packages'. Though if one of the packages has 'quantal' in the version (and not quassel, the irc client, in the name), that would indicate something is amiss in your sources.list.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oavxe9G.png

Comment: That is actually safe: it's the kernel version as present in 12.10, backported to 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I just didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

In my last login to Ubuntu Server, I suggest to use `do-release-upgrade`.
This may help any version to upgrade to the last version.