# Does upgrade affect Ubuntu or Kernel version?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, versions

1. Does upgrade lead to running the latest Ubuntu version ?
2. Or does it only upgrade the kernel ?
3. Is not upgrading the kernel the same thing as upgrading the
   operating system itself to a newer version ?

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` won't, according to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/274562/157741)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. When you're running dist-upgrade it will only upgrade your system according to the current software repository. That being said it will not upgrade 13.10 to 14.04. The do the full distribution upgrade, you will need to change your software repositories to 14.04.
2. If you run "sudo apt-get linux-generic", it will only upgrade the kernel. If you run "sudo apt-get upgrade" however it will upgrade all packages that have an update & it may include the kernel as well.
3. Technically speaking, yes, the kernel (Linux) is the operating system. That is why the upgrade option for apt-get is dist-upgrade which stands for "distribution upgrade". Kernel (Linux) + all applications make up the distribution. If you upgrade from Linux kernel version 3.12.x to 3.13.x, you have technically upgraded the "operating system", but you haven't upgraded your "distribution" which might still be Ubuntu 13.10 (and not Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Upgrade leads to running the latest Ubuntu version. This
   assumes that you are upgrading from the version that was the latest
   before the new release (You are running 13.10 and latest is 14.04)
2. The upgrade may (and usually does) involve kernel upgrade. But not
   every kernel upgrade is an OS upgrade
3. No. Upgrading kernel only upgrades the kernel. When the OS is
   upgraded, several other programs also get upgraded